# Issue with Request--downloading an empty image

Tags: python, image, request, python-requests

My request are downloading the images, but not properly. The images are empty. I know I am close to getting it correct, but I am not sure what I am missing--any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
fname ='testData.csv'

s = "dos2unix {}".format(fname)
inner_quote_grabber = re.compile(r'("[^"]*")', flags=re.M)
parenth_grabber = re.compile(r'\(([^)]*)\)', flags=re.M)



new_rows = []
matter = [0, 3,4]
file_counter = 0
file_prefix = 'images/'
file_out = 'outfile.csv'
with open(fname, 'r') as c:

 reader = csv.reader(c, delimiter=',')
 for row in reader:
  t_row = []
  #print( len(row), row)
  for i in matter:
   t_row.append(row[i])
  last_row = []
  print(row[7])
  for group in parenth_grabber.findall(row[7]):
   print('grabbing ', group)
   file_counter += 1
   click_clack = file_prefix + 'file_' + str(file_counter) +'.jpg'
   print('group:', group)
   req = requests.get(group)
   print('status_code', req.status_code)

   last_row.append(click_clack)
   with open(click_clack, 'wb') as f:
    req.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(req.raw, f)
    #f.write(text)
   file_counter += 1
  t_row.append(', '.join(last_row))
  with open(file_out, 'a') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(t_row)
```

Comment: your code is unreadable. Create bigger indentations.

Comment: I would start with `f.write(req.content)`